# Java-REST Service - JQuery/ajax - Strings are not beeing resolved, Integers do

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, service

I am having two @ Get within a RESTService in Java. They should return data from a SQL Server. A Client where JQuery-Ajax is running should receive the data record which is called. Everything works fine when I call the ID of the data record, then the data record is placed into the WebPage. but when I am entering a String Value for example a Name, nothing is happend. Has anybody an idear what am i doing wrong. (I am pretty new in programming.)

```
id = 3;
firstName=Holger

    function mitgliedDatenSuchenPerId(){
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/CustomerManagementWeb/api/v1/customers/"+firstName,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
        var mitglied = data;
        var aufgeloesst = JSON.parse(mitglied);
        $("#mitgliederId").val(aufgeloesst.id);
        $("#vorname").val(aufgeloesst.firstName);
        $("#nachname").val(aufgeloesst.lastName); 
        }
    });
    }

// parts of the RestService 

@GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Customer getCustomerById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Customer customer = em.find(Customer.class, id);
        return customer;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{firstName}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Customer getCustomerByName(@PathParam("firstName") String firstName) {
        Customer customer = em.find(Customer.class, firstName);
        return customer;
    }
```

Comment: Can you retrieve a Customer by name? I mean , does  this line ( em.find(Customer.class, firstName) actually retrieve a customer?

Comment: a very good question. But I dont know how to check this. Maybe I should find out what is in customer , but how. I cannot put an alert() on this, because that is Java. How can I check this?

Comment: You should debug it. Put a breakpoint on return customer, and run your application (you should start your server (e.g. Tomcat) in debug mode.